# Open Firefox extension preferences dialog from Add-ons dialog

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

What I want is simple - I'd like an  that will cause the normal Preferences dialog to open with my extension's preference pane highlighted.  I would have thought

```
<em:optionsURL>javascript:openPreferences("my_pref_pane");</em:optionsURL>
```

would have done it, but it doesn't.  I also would have thought

```
<em:optionsURL>chrome://myapp/browser/options.xul</em:optionsURL>
```

, with options.xul having <script>javascript:openPreferences("my_pref_pane"); window.close(); </script>, would have done it, but Firefox just displays the script in the resulting popup window and refuses to execute it.  How can I force Firefox to not assume I want to pop up some custom configuration dialog and just use the main preferences I already wrote?

(And why can't any helpful documentation exist? </rhetoricalQuestion>)

Comment: The Mozilla documentation gets easier to use as you get more familiar with it. AND it's a wiki so you can improve it yourself too! Anyway, putting the <script> tag in options.xul should work. Can you post your options.xul?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://npuff/locale/npuff.dtd">

<overlay id="npuff">
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        alert("asdf");
    </script>
</overlay>

Comment: options.xul should be a window of its own (quite likely, a prefwindow) not an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause Firefox to open the addons manager to your OWN addon's addon page.

```
var am = require("sdk/preferences/utils");
var self = require("sdk/self");

// Open the add-on manager with the preference page for this add-on.
am.open(self);
// Returns a promise that resolves once the tab is open.
```

Credit goes to freaktechnic [and his gist](https://gist.github.com/freaktechnik/34f4541c4f31c9842ec4).